# Angular2 web workers with ES5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have gone down a path of using Angular2 but writing ES5 code, which means that the examples and guidance I find usually must be translated from answers relevant to TypeScript.

Can someone help me with an ES5 version of:

Bootstrapping the application. In TypeScript I see it done as:

```
import {WORKER_APP_PLATFORM, WORKER_APP_APPLICATION} from "angular2/platform/worker_app";
import {platform} from "angular2/core";
platform([WORKER_APP_PLATFORM]).application([WORKER_APP_APPLICATION]).bootstrap(myApp)
```

Accessing the web_workers component:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/web_worker/worker';
@Component({ ... ])
```

I assumed the latter would be achieved by calling

```
ng.web_worker.worker.Component({ ... })
```

But that seems to not be the case: ng.web_worker is undefined.

The problem might be that I seem to not be able to include web_worker/ui.js properly. When I include it instead of bundles/angular2-all.umd.js I only get error messages about require being undefined. When I explicitly include RequireJS in my project I get a bunch of other errors.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you get this code?. Component is a part of angular 2 core, not web_worker. I only found that `worker_app` module exports some WORKER_RENDER, MessageBus, etc, I found it here: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/angular2/docs/web_workers/web_workers.md

Comment: I found this code example: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/web-workers-in-angular-2.0

Comment: Ok, thing you want to do is use angular 2 part in UMD format. But I couldn't found angular 2 umd build with web workers included. So the only way I can see now for ES5 is try to use angular 2 without UMD bundle, using SystemJS modules. (I hope I wrong and you can find easier solution)

Comment: this might be a bit crude, but have you thought of making this in typescript and check what the outputed js is? :)

Comment: Don't forget you can just paste Typescript into here, and it will show you the ES5 very quickly:  http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I ask, why do you want to do it with ES5? You can easily use SystemJS and ES6 if you don't like Typescript. Typescript would be almost identical to ES6.

In case you still want to do it with ES5, you need to change the imports to require calls:

```
var WORKER_APP_PLATFORM = require("angular2/platform/worker_app").WORKER_APP_PLATFORM;
var WORKER_APP_APPLICATION = require("angular2/platform/worker_app").WORKER_APP_APPLICATION;
var platform = require("angular2/core").platform;
platform([WORKER_APP_PLATFORM]).application([WORKER_APP_APPLICATION]).bootstrap(myApp)
```

Another example:

```
var Component = require('angular2/web_worker/worker').Component;
```

You get the idea. You also don't need RequireJS... You can use SystemJS. You should import the main file like this:

```
System.import("main")
```

SystemJS will resolve all the require calls async, but in the code, the require calls look sync.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We changed our minds about ES5 and reimplemented using TypeScript, which was not at all as hard as we had feared. Thanks for the help though